# R: nls2 misses the solution

Tags: r, nls

I'm trying to fit a bi exponential function:

```
t = seq(0, 30, by = 0.1)
A = 20 ; B = 10 ; alpha = 0.25 ; beta = 0.01
y = A*exp(-alpha*t) + B*exp(-beta*(t))
df = as.data.frame(cbind(t,y))
ggplot(df, aes(t, y)) + geom_line() +  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 50))
```

[image]

This problem can't be solve by a simple transformation like *log* so I wanted to use the `nls2` package:

```
library(nls2)

fo <- y ~ Ahat*exp(-alphahat*t) + Bhat*exp(-betahat*t)
fit <- nls2(fo,
            start = list(Ahat=5, Bhat=5, alphahat=0.5,betahat=0.5),
            algorithm = "brute-force",
            trace = TRUE,
            lower = c(Ahat=0, Bhat=0, alphahat=0, betahat=0),
            upper = c(Ahat=50, Bhat=50, alphahat=10,betahat=10))
fit
```

Here is the result:

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ Ahat * exp(-alphahat * t) + Bhat * exp(-betahat * t)
   data: NULL
    Ahat     Bhat alphahat  betahat 
     5.0      5.0      0.5      0.5 
 residual sum-of-squares: 37910

Number of iterations to convergence: 4 
Achieved convergence tolerance: NA
```

**I assume something is wrong in my code because :**

- data: NULL ?
- Why only 4 iterations  ?
- Hard to think nls2 didn't find a better solution than the starting point.
- The result is far from the solution

Comment: `data = NULL` since you did not supply a `data` argument.  The 4 iterations is a bug.  It actually only did 1 iteration since the arguments shown in the question only ask it to perform 1 iteration.   See https://github.com/ggrothendieck/nls2/issues/4  (Note that bug is that it reported 4 instead of 1 -- the fact that it only did 1 is correct since that is what you asked for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation, the `start` parameter should be a `data.frame` of two rows that define the grid to search in, or a `data.frame` with more rows corresponding to parameter combinations to test if you are using brute-force.  Also, `nls` will have trouble with your fit because it is a perfect curve, there is no noise.  The brute-force method is slow, so here is an example where the search space is decreased for `nls2`.  The result of the brute-force `nls2` is then used as the starting values with `nls` default algorithm (or you could use `nls2`), after adding a tiny bit of noise to the data.

```
## Data
t = seq(0, 30, by = 0.1)
A = 20 ; B = 10 ; alpha = 0.25 ; beta = 0.01
y = A*exp(-alpha*t) + B*exp(-beta*(t))
df = as.data.frame(cbind(t,y))

library(nls2)
fo <- y ~ Ahat*exp(-alphahat*t) + Bhat*exp(-betahat*t)

## Define the grid to search in,
## Note: decreased the grid size
grd <- data.frame(Ahat=c(10,30),
                  Bhat=c(10, 30),
                  alphahat=c(0,2),
                  betahat=c(0,1))

## Do the brute-force
fit <- nls2(fo,
            data=df,
            start = grd,
            algorithm = "brute-force",
            control=list(maxiter=100))
coef(fit)
#       Ahat       Bhat   alphahat    betahat 
# 10.0000000 23.3333333  0.0000000  0.3333333 

## Now, run through nls:
## Fails, because there is no noise
final <- nls(fo, data=df, start=as.list(coef(fit)))

## Add a little bit of noise
df$y <- df$y+rnorm(nrow(df),0,0.001)
coef((final <- nls(fo, data=df, start=as.list(coef(fit)))))
#        Ahat        Bhat    alphahat     betahat 
# 10.00034000 19.99956016  0.01000137  0.25000966 

## Plot
plot(df, col="steelblue", pch=16)
points(df$t, predict(final), col="salmon", type="l")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain why we need to use `nls` after using `nls2` ?

Comment: @Ricol You could do the same with `nls2`, just tell it to use the Gauss-Newton algorithm.  I wouldn't use `nls2` at all here, it is just a wrapper for `nls` allowing for situations where you don't have good starting values.  Once you have good starting values, you don't want to brute force, but instead use an algorithm that will get you a good result.

Comment: `nls2` does have an advantage over `nls` even here because it allows the starting value to be a previous nls2 fit so the last `nls` call in the answer could be shortened to just: `nls2(fo, data = df, start = fit)`

Answer (score 1):

Your data is  `null` because you didn't add in any data into the  `nls2` statement.

This is how  `nls2` needs to be set up:

```
nls2(formula, data = parent.frame(), start, control = nls.control(),
algorithm = c("default", "plinear", "port", "brute-force",
"grid-search", "random-search", "plinear-brute", "plinear-random"),
trace = FALSE, weights, ..., all = FALSE)
```

Take a look at [the official documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nls2/nls2.pdf) for a full example.